Prevent QMainWindow from enlarging QDockWidget when switching central widget
I have a main window with a dock widget and a central widget. The central widget can be changed depending on user choices, but the dock widget stays.
When the user did not resize the dock widget, everything is fine and changing the central widget did not affect dock widget size (which stays at size hint). However, when the user did resize the dock widget, it is then enlarged abnormally and take the central widget space.
Here is the animated gif of the problem:

And here is the code to reproduce the problem (with Qt5.15) :
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDockWidget>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QTimer>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget(const QString& aName, QSize aSize, QWidget * parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent), size(aSize)
    {
        static int COUNT = 0;
        static QStringList COLORS = { "LightBlue", "LightGreen", "LightSalmon" };

        auto label = new QLabel(tr("%1 (%2x%3)").arg(aName).arg(size.width()).arg(size.height()), this);
        label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
        label->setWordWrap(true);
        label->setStyleSheet(QString("QLabel { background-color: %1 }").arg(COLORS.value(COUNT++ % COLORS.size())));

        auto mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        mainLayout->addWidget(label);
    }

    QSize sizeHint() const override
    {
        return size;
    }

private:
    QSize size;
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        // Creating toolbar
        addToolBar("Tool bar")->addAction("Switch central Widget", this, &MainWindow::switchCentralWidget);

        // Creating main widget
        switchCentralWidget();

        // Creating dock widget
        auto dockWidget = new QDockWidget("My dock widget");
        dockWidget->setWidget(new Widget("DOCK WIDGET", {200, 400}, this));
        addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dockWidget);
    }

private slots:

    void switchCentralWidget()
    {
        setCentralWidget(new Widget("CENTRAL WIDGET", {300, 400}, this));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

I tried (unsuccessfully) to modify the size policy of both central and dock widgets.
The only thing that I found to prevent the dock enlarging is to set a temporary maximum  size (see below).
void switchCentralWidget()
{
    // Dirty hack
    for (auto dock : findChildren<QDockWidget *>()) {
        int width = dock->widget()->width();
        int maxWidth = dock->widget()->maximumWidth();
        dock->setMaximumWidth(width);
        QTimer::singleShot(1000, dock, [=] { dock->setMaximumWidth(maxWidth); });
    }

    setCentralWidget(new Widget("CENTRAL WIDGET", {300, 400}, this));
}


But it is dirty and causes me problems when the size hint of the dock widget is modified (one user action is to put another central widget and modify the dock widget font size).
What I would like is the dock widget to keep the same size as before the switching of central widget.

Did you try on any newer version of qt ? It looks like a bug that could've been fixed in the last 5 years that your version of qt was around in.

You may also consider using QStackedWidget instead of continuously replacing the central widget.

@AhmedAEK I am required to use Qt 5.15, but I tried with Qt 6.8 and it's the same.

@musicamante It works with QStackedWidget, thanks. But the main widgets are not related and cannot coexist. Beside, changes are not frequent and correspond to different usage of the application. But thanks to your idea I'm going to create a Single Widget wrapper to fix this issue.

@Niark You may also consider trying saveState() before switching the central widget, and call restoreState() with the previous result right after that. I'm not 100% it would work without flickering, but it's still worth trying. In any case, as soon as you find a solution that suits your needs, I'd suggest you to click the "Answer your question" button and explain what you did with a related [mre].

@musicamante I did try saveState() and restoreState(), but it didn't work. I will add my solution as suggested.

I was unable to prevent QMainWindow from enlarging the dock widgets when calling
setCentralWidget(). The solution was to create a wrapper for the central widget :
class WidgetWrapper : public QWidget
{
public:
    WidgetWrapper(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget(parent),
        layout(new QVBoxLayout(this)),
        widget(nullptr)
    {
        layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    void setWidget(QWidget *aWidget) {
        // Remove the current widget if it exists
        if (widget) {
            layout->removeWidget(widget);
            widget->hide();
            widget->deleteLater();
            widget = nullptr;
        }

        // Add the new widget
        if (aWidget) {
            layout->addWidget(aWidget);
            widget = aWidget;
        }
    }

private:
    QVBoxLayout * layout;
    QWidget * widget;
};

And use it like this :
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), centralWidget(new WidgetWrapper(this))
    {
        // Creating toolbar
        addToolBar("Tool bar")->addAction("Switch central Widget", this, &MainWindow::switchCentralWidget);

        // Init central widget
        setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        switchCentralWidget();

        // Creating dock widget
        auto dockWidget = new QDockWidget("My dock widget");
        dockWidget->setWidget(new Widget("DOCK WIDGET", {200, 400}, this));
        addDockWidget(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea, dockWidget);
    }

private slots:

    void switchCentralWidget()
    {
        centralWidget->setWidget(new Widget("CENTRAL WIDGET", {300, 400}, this));
    }

    WidgetWrapper * centralWidget;
};

